# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I am trying to create a function right now (instead of a package) that selects the column data that is currently inside of my OP_GUIDE_VIEW.

Just need a function that selects what's there. Not modifying anything, don't think I need parameters or anything either. What I have so far is the following; however, I cannot figure out this error to save my life: - Has an error @ IS C1 V_CURSOR;

What I have right now:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA AS

type v_cursor is ref cursor
return OPGUIDE_VIEW%rowtype;
 c2 v_cursor;
 r_c2 c2%rowtype;

 function fn_opview return v_cursor 
 is c1 v_cursor;
 begin
 open c1 for select * from OPGUIDE_VIEW;
 return c1;
 end;

 begin
 c2 := fn_opview;
 loop
 fetch c2 into r_c2;
 exit when c2%notfound;
 dbms_output.put_line(initcap(r_c2.JOB_NAME));
 end loop;
 close c2;
 end;

END PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA;
```

Error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:
constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national character
   nchar
```

Can give more information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create a package header and body at the same time.
You have to create an header, then a body, with separate queries; [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6006.htm) you find something more.
An example of how you could edit your code:

setup:

```
create table OPGUIDE_VIEW(JOB_NAME varchar2(100));
insert into OPGUIDE_VIEW values ('job1');
insert into OPGUIDE_VIEW values ('job2');
```

package creation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA AS
    FUNCTION fn_opview
        RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;

    PROCEDURE printData;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA AS
    FUNCTION fn_opview
        RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
        c1                                      SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c1 FOR SELECT * FROM OPGUIDE_VIEW;

        RETURN c1;
    END;

    PROCEDURE printData IS
        c2                                      SYS_REFCURSOR;
        r_c2                                    OPGUIDE_VIEW%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        c2    := fn_opview();

        LOOP
            FETCH c2 INTO r_c2;

            EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(INITCAP(r_c2.JOB_NAME));
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE c2;
    END;
END PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA;
```

Call your procedure:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2  PKG_OPGUIDE_COLLECTIONDATA.printData;
  3  end;
  4  /
Job1
Job2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Haven't ever had to work with PL-SQL before now, kinda shooting in the dark here. I knew I was missing something rather simplistic, sorry about that. - I'm aiming to return multiple values, not a singular value, would something of this accord do that? Was my function itself on the right track for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Figured it out after I had posted. Haha Sorry, mean to hit the solved button.